# How to have both pinch zoom and click feature in one layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-gesture

I have a layout that need to have pinch zoom feature and inside of that layout there is also many child(imageview) that will have a click feature. The click feature will open another activity.

I have use this code to create a custom layout https://gist.github.com/klarson2/4f737adf7f2577dc0fd09efb85eff3b1

But the problem is when first finger touch the child, then second finger touch anywhere it will not zoom.

Then I put in this code inside the zoom code (https://gist.github.com/klarson2/4f737adf7f2577dc0fd09efb85eff3b1):

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){

    switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(); //start time when first finger land
            startX = ev.getX() - prevDx;
            startY = ev.getY() - prevDy;
            break; //return false will go to frag

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
            if(clickDuration > MAX_CLICK_DURATION){
                // letting go from drag or zooming
                Log.i("Zoom1", " action pointer down test");
                return true; // remain at zoomlayout and do ontouch
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
            Log.i("Zoom1", " action up test");
            if(clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                // letting go from drag or zooming
                return true;
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
            if(clickDuration >= MAX_CLICK_DURATION){
                // to long on move, definitely is drag
                mode = Mode.DRAG;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
    }
return false;
}
```

Then another problem come out is that both finger touch the child and pinch zoom. The zoom offset.

[image]
this is how it show like

This is the idea of how the app will run. But will it work? I have try many ways but in the end there is a lot of error. Can anyone help me out. Thank you.

Comment: what you try before..please post some code.

Comment: You could use [Chrisbanes Photoview](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library. Can you give an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use TouchImageview

Comment: I have updated and put in what I have try. Thank you for helping me :)